# ReactNative drawer : blank screen

Tags: react-native, drawer, native-base

I am trying to use React-Native-Drawer in my React Native application (but the same problem appears with NativeBase drawer), but nothing shows in screen : neither ther drawer, nor the main content. However, if I log the jsx tag of the drawer component, it is neither null nor undefined.

Here the relevant snippet :

```
render(){

    const mainZone = <Text>Hello drawer !</Text>
    const sideBar = <Text>My drawer item</Text>

    const drawerZone = <Drawer
                        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
                        content={sideBar}
                        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
                        tapToClose
                      >
                      {mainZone}
                      </Drawer>;

    return drawerZone;
}
```

Here the versions

```
$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.43.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "custom-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "android": "curl 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android' -o 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle' && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chess-lib-js": "0.0.5",
    "native-base": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.4",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

So my question is just the following : did I miss something, some setup or a property in the drawer ? What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: facing the same issue right now, if you found solution, please share

Comment: Unfortunately still no solution. Gave up in favor of writing app with the Expo SDK.

Comment: Though I gave up this project, I think that the error comes from `content={sideBar}``which should be replaced with `content={() => sideBar}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NativeBase-KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) showcases all of NativeBase components.

Check for [Drawer](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/blob/master/js/AppNavigator.js) implementation